# Replace SQLite DB content when updating app

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, upgrade, new-operator

I have an iPhone app with a SQLite DB storing all the information similar to a book. The user only reads information off the DB and won't update it as the app does not allow update of data. When there is an upgrade, both the content of DB and the app are to be replaced. I want to know:

1. What is the best way to handle an upgrade as I want to over-write the DB entirely with a new one.
2. Actually I have now a new version pending review by apple and I have completely missed this issue. As this is my first iPhone application, I do not know what I can do to handle this situation. Can anyone help?

Comment: Where is your db stored? Within the app bundle? Or do you copy it to documents or Library folder on first app launch? This does not sound like a big issue. If needed, you can reject your uploaded binary so it does not get released.

Comment: Marcus, it is handled in the same way as the Recipe sample, it is copied to the Library folder on first app launch.

Comment: Should I reject my uploaded binary?

Comment: I understand that the new db file will not be copied and used when it is already existing at the target location (recipe sample does it like this). So If your updated app only works with the new db and might crash when using the old db, you should reject your own update. Before doing so, just test it: install your old development version and check what's happening when updating to the new version.

Comment: @Marcus, thank you for your answer. I am not sure whether doing an upgrade is the same as running it in the simulator. If the old db will be over-written by the new one when it is included in app bundle, it seems this is the best choice. If the db is added to project, does this mean it is included in the app bundle?

Comment: I assume your db file was added to your respective build-target and therefore is included in your app bundle. Following the recipe example, a new db will not be copied from the app bundle on app launch because there is already the db file from your first version copied. For new users of course this does not apply

Answer (score 0):

You can only alter files [in a couple subdirectories of the application’s home directory](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html). For a database file, you probably want the Documents directory (if it’s not already there at launch, just copy it from your app’s bundle), and then do a safe-replace (see NSFileManager). I do this exact thing in [MediBabble](http://medibabble.com/).

Comment: You can actually alter *any* file in the application's home directory, not only the Documents directory.

Comment: @jojaba: I was wrong, but apparently it’s only a subset of the home directory: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html